# How to get SIM info from Calllog.calls in android for dual sim

Tags: android, calllog, dual-sim

I am looking to read all incomming calls from the calllog and listing them in my app, but I am unable to get SIM info.
I tried using Calllog.calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID, but that seems to work for only single sim devices and not dual-sim.
I see theirs a property Calllog.calls.VIA_NUMBER, but that's only available for API >=24. but I need to support from API 16(Jelly Bean).

Its just a call log program, so I don't need to palace any calls/messages.